# Is there anyway to control which extensions are enabled/disabled via the workspace settings(.code-workspace)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there anyway to control which extensions are enabled/disabled via the workspace settings(e.g. via *.code-workspace file)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the answer is no, but there seems to be a feature request on this still pending, and perhaps some more useful information for you here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239